# ShowFileDialog1 Freezing

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

Okay, I have had the most aggravating problem with OpenFileDialog1. I have a program that I've been using for some 8 months, and in the past month, the program has begun to hang randomly when utilizing the OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() function. I have already read through all of the other posts about multi-threaded vs single threaded application. This did not fix it. Enabling the "Show Help" button did not fix it. I am mostly at a loss. here is a thorough walkthrough of the bug:

1. Run the application. I can always use the Open File button a few times with no problems. It freezes randomly after the program has been running for awhile.
2. The freeze happens after I push the ShowDialog button, and never displays the Open File Dialog window. The entire program locks up and hangs. If I pause it, Visual Studio doesn't show an error. It underlines the OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() in green, which is very odd.
3. I have found a way to break the freeze. Simply run a second instance of the program and use the OpenFileDialog function. As soon as it loads the file in the second instance, the first instance unfreezes. However, this is not a fix.
4. The only thing I can think of that may be causing this is the program also uses a WebBrowser1 control. It only seems to happen AFTER the WebBrowser control, which is on a seperate form, not the main form, has been initiated and utilized. Does this make any sense at all?

Thank you for anyone who can help me. I am about to tear my hair out.

Comment: OpenFileDialog can be troublesome on a dirty machine.  It loads all of the installed shell extensions into your program.  There are a lot of bad ones out there.  You might get some insight by enabling unmanaged debugging, you see the DLLs getting loaded in the Output window and with some luck you see the bad one in the Call Stack window when you use Debug > Break All.  Using SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to aggressively clean up is advisable.

Comment: Fwiw: you display the OpenFileDialog on a worker thread then look no further, these extensions can only work correctly on the main UI thread.  Diagnose with a breakpoint on the ShowDialog call, then Debug > Windows > Threads.

Comment: thank you Hans. I should also note, if I copy the executable file to another machine, i STILL get the error on the other machine. So I don't think it's machine specific. and if I find it is on another thread, how do I force the program back to the main UI thread?

Comment: Displaying dialogs on a worker thread is always a bug.  Nothing that should ever be "forced", you need to fix the bug.

Comment: 1) Is the OpenFileDialog (OFD) one that you created in code or dragged onto the form? If the former, you could try `OpenFileDialog1.Dispose()` as soon as it is finished with. 2) Do you have any network drives that might take a while to respond and make it appear that the OFD has frozen?

Comment: Initially I used a dialog dragged onto the form. I then adjusted the code to create a file dialog and deleted the control from the form. No luck. I've tried Dispose in the past and no luck. Last question is, why would the dialog be displayed on the worker thread? I don't understand how it got there.

Comment: nevermind, i have confirmed that the ShowDialog is occuring on the Main Thread when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It was quite unsolveable based on my description above, but hopefully I will help someone with this solution. The error is related to using the IE11 Emulation Control (11000) in the WebBrowser1 control. For some reason this interferes with OpenFileDialog and causes it to hang. I have no idea why. I changed my WebBrowser1 to use IE9 Emulation Control (9999) and the error has gone away. Thank you to those who looked into this. This is a registry entry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your program with [dnspy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases), And when the software freezes, you will be able to see within the dnspy the actual code even if it is in a third party DLL.